# How to write script for pinging Program for blogger

Tags: java, javascript, blogger, pinging

Hai i want to write a automaic pinging for my blogger when ever i update my blog ,
suggest me if any script already available or how to start

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Java, but here is a theoretical way to go about doing this:

Have the Javascript open http://pingomatic.com/ and perhaps have it enter in information automatically to ping your blog?

I know this isn't a legit answer, but hey, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to come across an auto ping for blogger and i have a Blogger help blog so i would have found it if it was there.